# while statement that goes with list and length

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

if i have this list

```
car=['Mazda','ford','Honda','corvette','Mercedes']
price=['300','450','350','490','500']
```

and i want to print the following sentence for each one at once

```
print ("that", car,"car price is:",price ,"in thousands dollar")
```

how to write the condition i usually use this but how to do it for a list ?

```
car=input("enter car name:")
price=float(input("price of the car:"))
```

because it will only print for the values that i have entered in

```
car=input("enter car name:")
price=float(input("price of the car:"))
```

Comment: Are the lists known or do you rely on user input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First using a for loop:

```
car = ['Mazda', 'ford', 'Honda', 'corvette', 'Mercedes']
price = ['300', '450', '350', '490', '500']
for i in range(len(car)):
    print ("that", car[i],"car price is:",price[i] ,"in thousands dollar")
```

Then a while loop:

```
i = 0
while(i < len(car)):
    print ("that", car[i],"car price is:",price[i] ,"in thousands dollar")
    i += 1
```

Demo Link

> https://repl.it/repls/AcclaimedFaroffProtocol

Comment: i tried what your code but it give me this error i+=1
    ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: i retry this and it gives me all of the them combined as a list in one sentence and it was also an infinite loop

Comment: this is the infinite output that appeared to me: that ['Mazda','ford','Honda','corvette','Mercedes'] car price is:['300','450','350','490','500'] in thousands dollar

Comment: can you check the above link which i mention in my answer run the code once

Comment: yeah that worked as water flow, thank you, however the code i'm trying to run is a little more complicated when i try to do the same code of yours it always gives me indentation error at i+=1

Comment: see the above link that finally worked, but its not giving me the right calculation of each one gross pay, its giving me the same for all of them.

Comment: although i didn't yet study the way you run the codes its completely new for me, but it worked well thank you so much for your help, may god bless you!

Comment: welcome please upvote and accept the answer if you got your answer. Happy to help you :-)

Answer (score 2):

> how to do it for a list?

With `zip()` function:

```
cars = ['Mazda','ford','Honda','corvette','Mercedes']
prices = ['300','450','350','490','500']

for car, price in zip(cars, prices):
    print("that {} car price is: {} in thousands dollar".format(car, price))
```

The output:

```
that Mazda car price is: 300 in thousands dollar
that ford car price is: 450 in thousands dollar
that Honda car price is: 350 in thousands dollar
that corvette car price is: 490 in thousands dollar
that Mercedes car price is: 500 in thousands dollar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can zip the two lists and that will work but I think a dictionary is the proper data structure for this task.

```
car_prices = {
'Mazda': 300,
'Ford': 450,
'Honda': 350,
'Corvette': 490,
'Mercedes': 500
}

for car, price in car_prices.items():
 print("that {} car price is: {} in thousands dollar".format(car,price))
```

Hope it helps

Comment: what if i want to use this len(list([list_name])) can this be appropriate?

Comment: @kimkazama I'm not sure if I know what you mean but you can get the length of the dictionary by simply using len(car_prices)